# Why isn't my JavaScript working with a photo gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a photo gallery and I can not switch through my photos. I don't understand what's going on. I debugged my code and I get this error:

> ncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLImageElement.onclick

What do I need to do to make make my gallery run smoothly?

I used [W3Schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) as my reference, but I have not been successful.

```js
function myFunction(imgs){

  var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
  var caption = document.getElementById("caption");
  mainImage.src = imgs.src;
  caption.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  mainImage.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>Welcome to the Rainforest</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- THUMBNAILS -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div id="thumbnails">
                    <img src="img/pexels-alleksana-4239623.jpg" id="" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="RainF1" onclick="myFunction(this);">
                    <img src="img/pexels-julia-volk-5769326.jpg" id="" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="RainF2" onclick="myFunction(this);">
                    <img src="img/pexels-mikhail-nilov-6965505.jpg" id="" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="RainF3" onclick="myFunction(this);" />
                    <img src="img/pexels-sakchai-ruenkam-6983731.jpg" id="" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="RainF4" onclick="myFunction(this);" />
                    <img src="img/pexels-yan-krukov-5479919.jpg" id="" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="RainF5" onclick="myFunction(this);"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- EXPANDED IMG -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div id="mainImage">
                    <img id="largeImage" src="img/pexels-alleksana-4239623.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
                    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- IMAGE TEXT -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="caption">
                    <p id="caption"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to tell the document about the javascript file using a `<script>` tag.

Comment: I added the script. They only things that changes on click is the captions.

Comment: Always make sure your HTML is [well-formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element). For instance, by *inspection*, after the document has been consistently formatted (indentation, etc.), manually or by an auto formatter. And/or use [the W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fpmortensen.eu%2Fworld%2FEditOverflow.php%3FLookUpTerm=don%27t%26OverflowStyle%3DNative). ***In this particular case***, the `div`s are unbalanced - there are ***12*** starting `div`'s (`<div`) and ***11*** ending `div`'s (`</div>`). Or in other words. a `div` is missing...

Comment: The HTML part is doubled (redundant) - but only the second is visible. Perhaps you intended to put in some CSS (the syntax hint suggests it)? Whatever it should be, can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69884960/edit)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're linking JavaScript files in your HTML content. For example,

```
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

You need to put it right before the closing `<body>` tag if the script needs to execute functions before the DOM has loaded, or else put it in the head section.

Next, if you haven't used the console yet, you need to open the debug console in your browser:

- Windows: <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
- Linux: <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
- macOS: <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

*[How to use the JavaScript debug console](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)*

When you open the console, you might see:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token "<"
> (In Firefox)

JavaScript will ignore the rest of your code after that.

Why *might* you be getting this error?

I don't know if you put the HTML in JavaScript code by accident on your post, but if that's your real code, take it out.

After all of that, the code should look like this:

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  let mainImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
  let caption = document.getElementById("caption");
  mainImage.src = imgs.src;
  caption.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  mainImage.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Welcome to the Rainforest</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--THUMBNAILS-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div id="thumbnails">
            <img src="img/pexels-alleksana-4239623.jpg" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="RainF1" onclick="myFunction(this);">
            <img src="img/pexels-julia-volk-5769326.jpg" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="RainF2" onclick="myFunction(this);">
            <img src="img/pexels-mikhail-nilov-6965505.jpg" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="RainF3" onclick="myFunction(this);" />
            <img src="img/pexels-sakchai-ruenkam-6983731.jpg" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="RainF4" onclick="myFunction(this);" />
            <img src="img/pexels-yan-krukov-5479919.jpg" id="" width="19.375%" height="19.5%" alt="RainF5" onclick="myFunction(this);"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--EXPANDED IMG-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div id="mainImage">
            <img id="largeImage" src="img/pexels-alleksana-4239623.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
            <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';" class="closebtn" style="cursor: pointer;">&times;</span>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--IMAGE TEXT-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="caption">
            <p id="caption"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You're lucky I noticed you had a missing close (`</div>`) right before the closing *body* tag. I fixed that too.

Also, you don't need a ridiculous amount of whitespace in your HTML.

You can learn more about JavaScript, HTML, and CSS in [MDN web documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: my gallery still does not switch in between pictures